# Parser Error while debugging new ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, parse-error

I created a new webform using "ADD NEW ITEM" icon in ASP.NET. I literally haven't added anything on its mark-up and code-behind yet but whenever I try to debug it (or view it in browser), I get a PARSER Error.

[image]

***All other webforms in the project works perfectly fine except for this new webform.***
I tried checking if DLLs are in the /BIN directory (and they are).

I haven't yet deployed this (I am not yet permitted to do so), so I'm not comfortable using the IIS Manager yet.

Please advice.
Thanks and Regards.

**Update: This is the vb code behind:**

```vb
Public Partial Class Real_Time
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

**And the mark-up:**

```asp
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Real_Time.aspx.vb" 

Inherits="Real_Time_PEN.Real_Time" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

As you can see. I haven't yet done anything on it.

Comment: Look at the file `Real_Time.aspx.vb`. What is the class name in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild the project which will compile the code-behind class, `Real_Time_PEN.Real_Time` into the DLL file; right now it isn't in there. Note that making a copy of an existing `.aspx` and `.aspx.vb` file or adding a new one to the project does not cause the class to be added to the DLL file automatically. You must build the project first.

Comment: Hi! I did that just now. But unfortunately, all the project related DLLs are now missing. And the other pages (which are previously working fine), are now experiencing "PARSER ERROR".

Comment: @lulutanseco That means your project isn't building/compiling because you have other errors in your project. You have to fix those first before you can do anything else.

Comment: hi! I saw an error in one of my files (I deleted a dropdownlist but did not delete the corresponding back-end code). I rebuild the project afterwards. I debugged the pages after and now they're all working. MANY THANKS :D